# Implementing range condition in a SQL query

Tags: sql, database

I have a table which stores percentage values for some combinations of data, like as shown below

```
Area_ID Period_ID Business_ID Percentage 
 1         1           1         50 
 1         1           2         40
```

I have another table which stores the threshold ranges, like

```
Threshold_ID  Percentage    Description
  1                20           Low
  2                40           Medium
  3                60           On Track
```

Now I have to find out which threshold the above combination falls in. It should assign Low if the percentage is less than 20 and Medium if the percentage is in between 20 and 40 and On Track if it is in between 40 and 60, High if it is greater than 60.

Is it possible to implement it in a SQL query. I tried using case, but I am not able to implement the range values in case.

Comment: You may want to add the query you attempted, its output, and why that output is incorrect.

Comment: With case, i can just compare the value for a combination against each threshold value. So i end up getting 3 rows for each combination as i am performing a join between the two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, an answer to your actual question: this is going to connect the two tables together, but the `WHERE` clause at the end will filter out the extra rows you are seeing. No idea what your actual table names are, so please replace them with whatever is necessary.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    Perc p
     LEFT JOIN 
    Thresh t ON 
        p.Percentage <= t.Percentage    -- return all ranges that are greater than the current value
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Thresh x 
    WHERE   -- eliminate ranges that are higher than this range and greater than the current value
        t.Percentage > x.Percentage AND         
        p.Percentage <= x.Percentage            
  )
```

Performance on that is likely not so great, since that extra `WHERE NOT EXISTS` will slow you down.  A far, far better model would be (written on SQL Server, since I don't have a db2 instance available to me:

```
CREATE TABLE #Threshold
  (
    Threshold_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    PercentageStart INT,
    PercentageEnd INT,
    Description VARCHAR(20)
  )

INSERT INTO #Threshold 
  (
    PercentageStart,
    PercentageEnd,
    Description
  )

SELECT 0, 20, 'Low'
UNION 
SELECT 21, 40, 'Medium'
UNION
SELECT 41, 60, 'On Track'
UNION
SELECT 61, 100, 'High'


CREATE TABLE #Percentage (Percentage INT)

INSERT INTO #Percentage 
SELECT 40
UNION
SELECT 50


SELECT *
FROM 
    #Percentage p 
     INNER JOIN 
    #Threshold t ON 
        p.Percentage BETWEEN t.PercentageStart AND t.PercentageEnd


DROP TABLE #Percentage
DROP TABLE #Threshold
```